# Calculate modulo large number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

How do I calculate 4^23 mod 31? I think it can be done using Euler's Totient Function, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a relatively easy example.  $4^{23}=2^{46}$.  Now, since $2^5=32\equiv1\pmod{31}$,

$$2^{46}=(2^5)^9\times2=32^9\times2\equiv1\times2\equiv2\pmod{31}$$

Comment: Beat me to the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough to do by successive squaring:

\begin{align*}
4^1 &\equiv 4 \pmod{31} \\
4^2 &\equiv 16 \pmod{31} \\
4^4 &\equiv 16^2 \equiv 8 \pmod{31} \\
4^8 &\equiv 8^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{31} \\
4^{16} &\equiv 2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{31}
\end{align*}

Now use the fact that $23 = 16 + 4 + 2 + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the laws of exponents to change the numbers representation:

$$4^{23}=\left(2^2\right)^{23}=2^{46}=2\cdot 2^{45}$$
$$=2\cdot \left(2^5\right)^9$$
$$=2\cdot (32)^9$$
$$=2\cdot (31+1)^9$$

Using binomial expansion:

$$2\cdot \left(31^9\cdot 1^0+9\cdot 31^8\cdot 1^1+\cdots +9\cdot 31^1\cdot 1^8+31^0\cdot 1^9\right)$$
$$=2\cdot 31^9\cdot 1^0+2\cdot 9\cdot 31^8\cdot 1^1+\cdots +2\cdot 9\cdot 31^1\cdot 1^8+2\cdot 31^0\cdot 1^9$$

In this new representation of $4^{23}$ we can notice that every term in the expression is divisible by $31$ except for the last term "$2\cdot 31^0\cdot 1^9$" which equals $2$.
This means that if you divide $2^{43}$ by $31$, the remainder will be $2,$ thus $4^{23} \bmod31=2$.

This question can be answered without a pen and paper!

Comment: For multicharacter exponents, enclose them in braces.   So 4^{23} gives $4^{23}$ instead of 4^23 giving $4^23$

Answer (score 0):

By [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) and [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) $2^{15}\equiv \left(\frac{2}{31}\right)\equiv 1\pmod{31}$ (because $31\equiv -1\pmod{8}$). Therefore:$$4^{23}\equiv 2^{46}\equiv 2^{46\bmod 15}\equiv 2^1\equiv 2\pmod{31}$$